# Updating value of an observable without applying the subscribe

Tags: rxjs, angular-forms, rxjs-observables

I subscribe to an `Observable` with a `pairwise` pipe in order to get previous and new value.

But sometime I would like to tell the `Observable` that the value has been updated without applying the `subscribe` function. It will ensure that the `previousValue` is always updated but without always applying the subscribe function.

```
// Listen to FomControl -> update value variable.
this.valueChangesSubscription = this.control.valueChanges
    .pipe(startWith(this.defaultValue), pairwise())
    .subscribe(async ([previousValue, newValue]) => {
        // Do something
    });
```

I update the value of the `formControl` and sometime emitting the event, sometimes not:

```
this.control.setValue(formattedValue, { emitEvent });
```

But I would like that even if the event is not emitted, the `previousValue` of the `subscribe` function will be the real `previousValue` and not juste the latest emitted one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `filter` operator to filter the subscribed result

```js
private myBooleanValue = false;

// Listen to FomControl -> update value variable.
this.valueChangesSubscription = this.control.valueChanges
    .pipe(
       startWith(this.defaultValue), 
       pairwise(),
       // It will never emit a value to subscribe since its false
       filter(([previousValue, newValue]) => this.myBooleanValue),
     )
    .subscribe(async ([previousValue, newValue]) => {
        // Do something
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but this is never going to the `subscribe` function. What I would like is a '`emitWithSubscribeApplied` and `emitWithoutSubscribeApplied` kind of functions. I've searched a way to pass metadata alongside the event but it doesn't seems feasible.

Comment: It will if you change the value of `myBooleanValue` to true, what is the problem with that ?

Comment: I don't control every value change of the `formControl`. I don't want to miss an event because 2 events has been emitting nearly at the ame time: one programmatically and one through an user action (typing text in an input, ...). If I set the boolean to `false` when emitting programmatically and don't reset it to true before the "user event" is being called than I would miss that action.